# Run batch file AFTER all other programs at Windows inicialization

Tags: initialization, registry

I have a set of programs running at Windows startup, some called from Registry and others called from Start Menu (Initialization).

I'm trying to have a batch file loaded and showed its screen AFTER all other programs has had loaded.

I tried changing their entries in Registry (Run subkey, also Wow6232Node) and Start Menu without success. That batch file is almost always the first screen I got and it is not desirable as I need. It has to be the last screen showed.
Firefox uses to be the last one.

So, how to load Firefox (and all others) BEFORE that batch file?
How to delay or put a "sleep" command within Windows start up for a given program?

Thx.

Comment: I'd add that important thing is to set focus to batch file running after all other programs had loaded. My goal is to have that batch file in foreground and focused.

Answer (score 0):

For those users with the same question on how to put a delay, after some searching, I found a solution. My script ended being like this:

```
@echo off
rem PING 111.111.111.111 -n 1 -w 15000 >NUL
timeout /t 15
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PGP Corporation\PGP Desktop\PGPtray.exe" /m "somefile.pgd"
start C:\somefolder\somefile.exe
exit
```